# How to use AG-Grid in React? I am getting Build error

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, spfx

Below is the component file:

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
import {AllCommunityModules} from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';



export default class FormGrid extends React.Component<IFormGridProps,IFormGridState> {
   constructor(props: IFormGridProps, state: IFormGridState){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     columnDefs: [
      { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
      { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
      { headerName: "Price", field: "price" }],
     rowData: [
      { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
      { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
      { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }]
     }
    }
public render(): React.ReactElement<IFormGridProps> {
return (
  <div className={ styles.formGrid }>
    <div className={ styles.container }>
      <div className={ styles.row }>
      <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={ {height: '200px', width: '600px'} }>
      <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
        rowData={this.state.rowData}
        modules={AllCommunityModules}>
      </AgGridReact>
      </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
 }
 }
```

The error is below:

> error TS2339: Property 'columnDefs' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>...'

IFormGridState.ts file is below:

```
export interface IFormGridState{
   columnDefs: any,
   rowData: any
}
```

I couldn't understand why the error is coming. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the "@ag-grid-community/all-modules" package installed
I tried your code and it compiled fine but I had to have above package installed. Can you also paste your imports?

Additional notes/tips:

- On line 2 you can only pass `props` as an argument for React Class    components (that wouldn't give you such an error though)
- There's no need to add type for your render method

Comment: ag-grid modules are installed. I have added the imports in the the question

Comment: Where are you getting the styles.formGrid and similar from? If that's not the case then try debugging step by step. First make sure that all but the `
<AgGridReact
        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
        rowData={this.state.rowData}
        modules={AllCommunityModules}>
      </AgGridReact>
`
section compiles. So just remove that temporarily.
Then if above works fine then replace the variables from the state with empty arrays like here:
`
<AgGridReact
        columnDefs={[]}
        rowData={[]}
        modules={AllCommunityModules}>
      </AgGridReact>`